# Angular - Is there a way to know what is the user's device time format ? 24h system vs 12 am/pm system

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to know if the user's time format is 24h or 12h system in Angular ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try with `Date.toLocaleTimeString()`, take a look maybe it is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar a while back, this is what worked for me.

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 12, 3, 0, 0));
var dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString();


if (dateString.match(/am|pm/i) || date.toString().match(/am|pm/i) )
{
    //12 hour clock
    console.log("12 hour");
}
else
{
    //24 hour clock
    console.log("24 hour");
}
```